# Health check MassTransit and Rabbitmq

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am planing to implement Health check middle-ware in ASP .net core application.
For example to check if the DB is healthy, I open and close a db connection. Similarly, what is the best approach to check if MassTransit is healthy (i.e. it can connect and send/publish messages without an issue)?

Comment: For MassTransit/service-level health checks, I implemented special "Smoke Test" endpoints and did request/response messaging pattern to verify communication and also check any DB connections from the app config similar to what you've already done.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question. But I had the same question and found this [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Rabbitmq/)

This is the corresponding [github repo](https://github.com/xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks)

use like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddRabbitmq("amqp://username:password@host:port/vhost"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for your healthcheck, you can use the implemented healthcheck services from .netcore 2.0

in the startup you can use:

```
services.AddHealthChecks(checks =>
{
    checks.AddSqlCheck("adsales", Configuration["AdsalesConnection"]);
});
```

i think you can add your check for rabbitmq here to.
But then again, why would you, I've you put in a heartbeat with the setup, your connection would be closed by the server. And your push-api- `received`-eventhandler wouldn't get any messages there.

Just a thought...

let me know when you've implemented it! Just curious!

Comment: Thanks. Are u referring to https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/HealthChecks/tree/dev/src? I don't think its available for .netcore 2.0 yet. I implemented asp.net core middleware instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x
I want a way to test masstranist connection,

Comment: yess, that is the one! It is already available, I am already using it ;)
I don't have any experience with Masstranist, bu I'm guessing it works the same. But sorry, can't help you there!

Comment: Do you know/have the nuget to install healthcheck?